# Using variables inside a function in another python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

i cant seem to make this work.

I have 2 python files, lets say a.py and b.py

**in a.py is this:**

```
def foo():
    global name
    name = "foo"
    import b
    b.bar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
```

**in b.py this:**

```
import a

def bar():
    name = a.name
    print(name)
```

I have three different question in relation to this code:

1. Why do i get the error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'name'`
   I know for certain that b.py cant access the variable defined in the function in b.py but how do i solve this?
2. does global in this case changes anything? if not, why?
3. i tried doing `name = a.foo.name` instead of `name = a.name` but this doesnt do the trick either and gives me: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'`,
   is this even practicable in any case and what did i do wrong?

Thanks for taking the time and sorry if this seems obvious to some of you, i'am still getting into this.

Comment: Where do you define `name` in `a.py`?

Comment: @ozgur yes it's defined in the function foo() in a.py

Comment: variables defined inside a function are bound to function's local scope so they are not visible outside of the function. You need to define `name` somewhere in a.py outside of `foo()`.

Comment: @ozgur problem is, later i want to change ´name´ to something else and when i define it outside of the function it will always get reset when importing right?

Comment: No actually, after `foo()` is executed once, variable `name` will remain `"foo"` in the current process even if you `import a` again.

Comment: @ozgur - `global name` is sufficient to bind `name` in the module's namespace. Lyux's code would work if both `a` and `b` were imported.

Comment: @tdelaney I didn't say it wouldn't work. I said once `foo()` is called, `name` won't get reset when `a.py` is imported repeatedly within the same process.

Comment: @ozgar - You said: "You need to define name somewhere in a.py outside of foo()"_ - that's not true, OP used `global` and that is sufficient. _"variable name will remain "foo" in the current process even if you import a again"_ - only half true since `a.py` is in fact loaded twice.

Comment: @ozgur No, the `global` keyword is sufficient to put `name` in the module namespace as soon as `foo` is run. I think we are just spamming the question at this point. Read up on `global` and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts aren't modules. Its something of a mind bender but when you run `python3 a.py`, `a.py` isn't a module (or more properly, its a module named `__main__`) and it will be reloaded when you import.

Suppose I have *c.py*

```
print('hello')
if __name__=="__main__":
    import c
```

When I run it I get

```
hello
hello
```

To illustrate with your example, if I change *b.py* to

```
import __main__

def bar():
    name = __main__.name
    print(name)
```

It works. But only kindof because if somebody imports `a` you've still got two modules and two copies of the variable.

If you want shared data, they have to be in imported modules, not top level scripts. When I want shared data, I create a separate module that doesn't import anything (or only imports from the standard library) and it is either empty or has defaults for the variables I want to share.

Comment: So i guess shared data would work, i created c.py for a test purpose and only wrote name="foo" into it and made it work, but the thing is, if i want to change the "shared" variable name in c.py to let's say "bar" how would i do this from a.py for example?

Comment: If I understand your question, its just `c.bar = c.foo`. And if you wanted to get rid of the original variable completely it would be `del c.foo`.

Comment: c.py is only `name="foo"` now, how do i change the variable `name` out of a.py so there is now `name="bar"` in c.py, you may wonder why i ask this, its because later on b.py shall get the variable `name` from c.py with the value `name="bar"` this is what i understand by "shared data"

Comment: Any of the modules can change the variable with `c.name = "bar"`. After that, any module referencing `c.name` gets `"bar"`.

Comment: alright, got it, big thanks for your patience with me!

Answer (score 0):

1, 2) The **specific purpose** of `if __name__ == "__main__":` is to contain code that *will not run* when the file is `import`ed. Since `foo()` is inside that block and nowhere else, the `foo` function does not run when `import a` happens; therefore the `global name` is not assigned to; therefore the `a` module does not have a `name` global; therefore `b` cannot refer to the nonexistent module global with `a.name`.

3. `a.foo.name` cannot fix the problem because, although `a.foo` exists (there is a `foo` function defined in the `a` module at the top level), it does not have a `name` attribute. The local variables in a function's code are **not part of** the function object; they exist *only temporarily, while the code is running*, and are not inherently part of **any** object. (Even if you call `locals()`, that *creates a new* `dict`, and assigns the local variables as values.)

It **is** possible to assign attributes to a function - for example, in `a.py`:

```
def foo():
    pass
foo.name = "bar"
```

And such an attribute can be used from outside, including in another module:

```
# b.py
import a
print(a.foo.name)
```

But this is entirely orthogonal to what the function actually does, or to using it for any particular purpose.