# Accessing a function variable from another file in python

Tags: python, function, file, variables

I have two files `File1` and `File2`. In `File1` I have a function `detect()` defined as:

```
def detect():
    s = // some operations
```

I need to access this variable `s` in `File2`.

I have tried declaring the variable as `global` but it has not worked.

How can I access the variable without creating a class as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972184/how-to-access-a-variable-from-a-function-which-is-in-another-file-in-python) or by using `__main__` as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255592/using-variables-inside-a-function-in-another-python-file) ??

Comment: how about having the `detect()` function return the variable?

Comment: One way would be to have the detect function return the s value.  Then you can call detect from anywhere.

Comment: I cannot call the function as it performs may other operations but I need to only access that variable. I'll need to call the function in order to access the variable which I don't want to.

Comment: Accessing a function's local variable without calling it doesn't make any sense. What's the X in this [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: `s` doesn't have a value until `detect()` is actually evaluated, so what you're asking for doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I think I fell into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Thanks for post. Brought a lot of clarity for asking question!

Comment: Actually, I wanted to pass the value of  `TimeElapsed` to run the function `detect()` to a function in another file.Previously, the variable `TimeElapsed` was calculated inside `detect()` and the problem was that the File Structure was huge and finding the two function calls was confusing. Apparently, I realized that both these functions were actually called by the `__main__` function and not within separate files. Hence, I resolved it by tracking the time of execution of `detect()` in the `__main__` function and passing the `TimeElapsed` to the other function which is defined in `File2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function detect must be run to init its local variables.

```
def detect():
    detect.tmp = 1

def b():
    print(detect.tmp)

detect()
b()
```

of course you can import one python file as python module and call its functions like

```
from File1 import detect
print(detect.tmp)
```